# Azure publish can't use saved RDP password?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, rdp, azure-configuration

Every time we publish our Azure project (all machines in our team/at home as well) it always asks us to re-enter our RDP password.

This is a bit annoying as it means the files check out and we have to keep entering the password.

The error message is "The existing Remote Desktop credentials could not be loaded in this environment. Re-enter the desired password".

Anyone got any idea what is up? Its a bit frustrating.

Comment: Is it a Staging or Production role?

Comment: We deploy to staging. However pretty sure the same thing happened when I pushed a demo site straight to production

Comment: My .rdp file for `production` does save the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was because we were publishing to different instances with the same configuration and not using a fixed RDP cert. It was re-generating the certificate each time.

If you have this problem upload the cert to each cloud service you are deploying to and use the one cert across all deployments.